# how to prevent vertical Stepdown

Tags: html, css

I searched for preventing step down and tried to apply the solutions I found on my code but none of them worked. Maybe because my stepdown is vertical and because it's for an element inside other elements.

in my code, I float the time classes to the left but they appear like a stair; they don't all float to left. I know that I'm missing something but I don't exactly what and where.

```
<ul class="lias">
    <li class="tablecell">
        <div class="count" >
            <img src="Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px">
            <img src="message.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px" >
        </div>
        <div class="count" >
            <samp>
                <h3><a href="http://www.facebook.com/wisam.okkeh">sho hl 6a2s ?</a></h3>
            </samp>
        </div>
        <div class="time" >
            <h3>2 day ago</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="tablecell">
        <div class="count" >
            <img src="Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px">
            <img src="message.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px" >
        </div>
        <div class="count" >
            <samp>
                <h3><a href="http://www.facebook.com/wisam.okkeh">sho hl 6a2s ?</a></h3>
            </samp>
        </div>
        <div class="time" >
            <h3>2 day ago</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="tablecell">
        <div class="count" >
            <img src="Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px">
            <img src="message.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px" >
        </div>
        <div class="count" >
            <samp>
                <h3><a href="http://www.facebook.com/wisam.okkeh">sho hl 6a2s ?</a></h3>
            </samp>
        </div>
        <div class="time" >
            <h3>2 day ago</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="tablecell">
        <div class="count" >
            <img src="Cute-Ball-Go-icon.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px">
            <img src="message.png" style="height:30px; width:30px ; margin:0px" >
        </div>
        <div class="count" >
            <samp>
                <h3><a href="http://www.facebook.com/wisam.okkeh">sho hl 6a2s ?</a></h3>
            </samp>
        </div>
        <div class="time" >
            <h3>2 day ago</h3>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The css code

```
.count { display:inline-block}
.time {float:right; display:inline-block;}
.tablecell{white-space:nowrap; border-top:3px solid gray;list-style:none;}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9tg5t25/) for the code
How can I float all `time`s elements to right?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x9tg5t25/1/

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks, it Worked. I'll be grateful if you just add an explanation how it worked, and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also clear the right float with `clear:right`. Then also add `overflow:auto` to the list item so that it encompasses the floated elements.

```
.count {
    display:inline-block
}
.time {
    float:right;
    clear:right;
    display:inline-block;
}
.tablecell {
    white-space:nowrap;
    border-top:3px solid gray;
    list-style:none;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/x9tg5t25/2/)**